# spark scala error: value _1 is not a member of Iterable[(Int, String, String)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

```
scala> data.take(5).foreach(println)


(Diamond Fear No Evil Compound Bow Package,CompactBuffer((45,Diamond Fear No Evil Compound Bow Package,599.99)))
(Fitness Gear Pro Half Rack,CompactBuffer((11,Fitness Gear Pro Half Rack,349.99), (16,Fitness Gear Pro Half Rack,349.99)))
(Nike Men's Air Max 2014 Running Shoe,CompactBuffer((19,Nike Men's Air Max 2014 Running Shoe,149.99), (49,Nike Men's Air Max 2014 Running Shoe,149.99)))
(Nike Men's Andrew Luck Jersey - Home Game Ind,CompactBuffer((59,Nike Men's Andrew Luck Jersey - Home Game Ind,100.0)))
(Diamondback Grind BMX Bike 2014,CompactBuffer((10,Diamondback Grind BMX Bike 2014,199.99), (43,Diamondback Grind BMX Bike 2014,199.99)))
```

if run a query

```
scala> data.map(x => x._2._1).take(5).foreach(println)

<console>:34: error: value _1 is not a member of Iterable[(Int, String, String)]
          data.map(x => x._2._1).take(5).foreach(println)
```

Comment: can you format your question and enlighten us what you are trying to do?

Comment: This error is **very** clear. Your second element of tuple is `Iterable` not a tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets analyze the action `data.map(x => x._2._1).take(5).foreach(println)` you are performing on your data `(Diamond Fear No Evil Compound Bow Package,CompactBuffer((45,Diamond Fear No Evil Compound Bow Package,599.99)))`

`x._2` is `CompactBuffer((45,Diamond Fear No Evil Compound Bow Package,599.99))` which is not a `tuple` so you can't access elements of `compactBuffer` as that of the tuple using `underscore` sign `_1`

And thats what the error means

`CompactBuffer` is an `iterator` containing `Tuple3`, so you can iterate over it and access elements using `underscore` sign as below.

```
data.map(x => x._2.map(y => y._1)).take(5).foreach(println)
```

which will give you results as

```
List(45)
List(11, 16)
......
```

whereas doing

```
data.map(x => x._2.map(y => y._3)).take(5).foreach(println)
```

would give you

```
List(599.99)
List(349.99, 349.99)
..........
```

and so on.

Comment: that's works. if i load to another var it shows                                                                                                                      scala> var datalist = data.map(x => (x._2.map(y => y._1),x._2.map(y => y._2)))
datalist: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Iterable[Int], Iterable[String])] = MapPartitionsRDD[31] at map at <console>:33

Comment: yes, thats because map would create a collection. :) thanks for the upvote and acceptance :)